# I cannot read spaces and enters in c++ using devc++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hi I am new here and I have little problem I guess. I want my program to change one character in whole text in text file. For example I want to change all A to G. But when I read it ,it does not even read spaces and enters. Also I want to write eddited text in new textfile. Thanks for help.

Comment: *"For example I want to change all A to G. But when I read it ,it does not even read spaces and enters"* - Can you please show us the code you've written?

Comment: I assume you use the `>>` input operator? Don't. Read in bulk into a buffer, modify the buffer and write it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning you should load whole file.

```
std::ifstream is("file.txt");
is >> std::noskipws;
std::istream_iterator<char> start(is), end;
std::vector<char> buffer(start, end);
```

`is >> std::noskipws` prevents stream from skipping white characters like space or enter. Then replace characters using `std::replace(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), 'A', 'G');`.

Now simply save file:

```
std::ofstream out("file.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
```

You may want to read something about those:
[`std::ostreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator), [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace).